# RPi 3 or Compute model?

Tags: pi-3

A working in a project where the product going to be sold in about 100 ps/year and it use a RPi3 as computer. It is mounted upside down on a motherboard. It has some connectors and simple perhiperials.
It has now been discussed if the RPi3 can be replaced with the Compute unit. It seems more slim and cheap. 
I know there it must be more hardware attached to it such as Ethernet module if we using Compute. But are there any more disadvantages with the Compute vs standard RPi? Such as availability or prices in long term?

Regards

Comment: Hello and welcome. I doubt that anyone will be able to give solid insight on availability or princing in the long term, save the Foundation itself (though the probability that they will is pretty close to zero).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your use of the pi. If it is in the use needes for the Pi 3, you can use that, the computer module uses some weird stuff. Perhaps if you need it for a lighter workload and are able to overlook the hardware differences, you could use the Pi Zero, which would have the lighter processing power, but might be less power-hungry and cheaper and easier to acquire then the compute module.

Comment: The RPi receives data through the eth0 port, sorting it, and then transfer it to the serial port. It is not much data. I will look into the Pi Zero.

Comment: @NalleHaddock Please accept the answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again and again after years.